# DropWizard 400 error on GET when use @JsonInclude(NON_DEFAULT)

Tags: java, json, jackson, dropwizard

I get a `400 unable to parse JSON` error when i send a GET to `games/` using Postman.

GameResource:

```
@Path("/games")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class GameResource {
    @GET
    public List<Game> getGames() {
        ArrayList<Game> l = new ArrayList<Game>();
        l.add(new Game(100));
        return l;
    }
}
```

Game:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Game {
    protected int id; 
    protected int whoseTurn;
    protected int winner;
    protected char[][] board;

    public Game(int id, int turn, int winner, char[][] board) {
        this.id=id;
        this.whoseTurn=turn;
        this.winner=winner;
        this.board=board;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }       

    public int getWhoseTurn() {
        return whoseTurn;
    }

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)
    public int getWinner() {
        return winner;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public char[][] getBoard() {
        return board;
    }
```

If I remove the annotation on `getWinner`, it works fine. Why might this be? Is `Include.NON_DEFAULT` not supported by DropWizard? Other annotations seem to work OK...

Comment: You are creating the Game object using 'new Game(100)' constructor but I don't see it in the code. Is there more code for the Game class?

Answer (score 4):

Include.NON_DEFAULT won't work unless you have a no-arg constructor, for example, the following will work (without setters it's fairly useless).

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

public class Game {
    protected int id;
    protected int whoseTurn;
    protected int winner = -1;
    protected char[][] board;

    public Game() { }

    public Game(int id, int turn, int winner, char[][] board) {
        this.id = id;
        this.whoseTurn = turn;
        this.winner = winner;
        this.board = board;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getWhoseTurn() {
        return whoseTurn;
    }

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)
    public int getWinner() {
        return winner;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public char[][] getBoard() {
        return board;
    }
}
```

This works because there is a default no-arg constructor and winner has a default value. The [JavaDoc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_DEFAULT) might provide you more help.